# How to confirm user in Cognito User Pools without verifying email or phone?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am using [Amazon Cognito Identity SDK for JavaScript](https://github.com/amazon-archives/amazon-cognito-identity-js) (deprecated).

I created new pool without verifying email and phone_number.

By default, users aren't confirmed in Cognito User Pools, so I need to do this manually.

How to confirm user in Cognito User Pools without verifying email or phone?

Comment: you can also use this by skipping the otp step they mention https://stackoverflow.com/a/66267032/8782229

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Actually, AWS has recently added the ability to verify email and verify phone number in the **pre-signup** lambda as well. You basically need to set **autoVerifyEmail** and **autoVerifyPhone** in the lambda and they will get verified. 
More info in the [official documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-triggers.html#cognito-user-pools-lambda-trigger-syntax-pre-signup).

```
"response": {
    "autoConfirmUser": boolean
    "autoVerifyEmail": boolean
    "autoVerifyPhone": boolean
}
```

Answer (score 44):

I hope this will help someone else.

To do this you can add this Lambda function:

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    event.response.autoConfirmUser = true;
    event.response.autoVerifyEmail = true;  // this is NOT needed if e-mail is not in attributeList
    event.response.autoVerifyPhone = true;  // this is NOT needed if phone # is not in attributeList
    context.done(null, event);
};
```

Then navigate to AWS Cognito's General settings >> Triggers and add this Lambda function to 'Pre sign-up' - click the drop down list and select Lambda function with above code.

If you only use 'preferred_username' (if no e-mail or phone # is used) setting event.response.autoConfirmUser to true is sufficient.

Comment: I've added this Lambda and my users are auto confirmed. Will this allow a user to use their IAM credentials for S3, etc? Can I then prompt the user to "verify your email address" and restrict access to functionality until the email is verified?

Comment: This does not work if you create a user using the sdk. It only works if user signsup through custom UI. Do you have a solution?

Comment: But how do you add a pre-signup lambda function?

Answer (score 11):

I think the accepted answer is problematic. OP's question is how to confirm a user **without verifying their email**. But the solution **will** verify the user's email.

If you want to confirm a user with an unverified email (or phone), you can use `AdminConfirmSignUpCommand`. It is the intended way to confirm a user without having them do it, as per official docs:

[image]

Unlike `ConfirmSignUpCommand`, `AdminConfirmSignUpCommand` doesn't need a code. You can implement this command after signup in your API or as a Custom Message Trigger (effectively confirming the user when the email is sent).

Now, the user can log in, but the email must be confirmed still.

Comment: Best answer. Now my users can login but after I will want email confirmation

Comment: Best answer for me. I want to email verify some users but not others