# Require verification of both email and phone

Tags: amazon-cognito

If a user provides both an email and phone, I need to require both to be verified. It looks like there isn't a way to do this without extra steps as described here

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-email-phone-verification.html

Is there a way to require both verifications?

Currently it looks like I have to wait for phone number to be verified, verify phoneNumbber first. After that call initiateAuth to get an access token to retrieve the userInfo and check if email needs verification, and send verification code out. From testing I saw that email verification does not block the initiateAuth request so a getUser request would need to be made before every initiateAuth request to see if verification is needed and not return an access token if email still needs verification.

Answer (score 1):

I am on the Cognito team. The scenario described is not possible at this point (requiring email and phone number verification before sign in). If both phone number and email require verification, if a phone number is present in the user attributes, the verification code is sent to the phone number, it is prioritized. Also, the calls to verifyUserAttribute which would enable you to verify email require an AccessToken to mark email as verified.

Comment: How would one handle a scenario where a user can enter both email and phone number and then using either one to log in? Why is the phone prioritized and the email completely ignored? I'm currently stuck in the scenario I'm describing and would love some feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatelly, Cognito will only send you an email verification link if you do not provide a phone number when registering. If you provide an empty phone number property value, and a valid email address, in this case it'll send the email.

This is really awful, because SMS messages sometimes don't reach the endpoint in real time.

Comment: E-mail messages are also not always delivered real-time

Answer (score 0):

If you want to verify the two contact methods in the registration flow for example, you could do this (you must have your own otp verification flow for example):

1. Create the user with admin powers without notifying the user of the registration

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cognito-idp/admin-create-user.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminCreateUser.html

```
aws cognito-idp admin-create-user --user-pool-id us-east-2_fggdfg --username 117979111  --user-attributes Name=email,Value=calderonr.robinson@gmail.com Name=phone_number,Value="+5732085654" Name=custom:id,Value="1179791" Name=name,Value="Robinson C" --message-action SUPPRESS
```

(This can be programmed after the otp verification that you develop)

2. Then assign the password to be confirmed

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cognito-idp/admin-set-user-password.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminSetUserPassword.html

```
aws cognito-idp admin-set-user-password --user-pool-id us-east-2_fggdfg --username 117979111 --password "loquesea" --permanent
```

3. Assigns as true the contact method that was verifying

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cognito-idp/admin-update-user-attributes.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminUpdateUserAttributes.html

```
aws cognito-idp admin-update-user-attributes --user-pool-id us-east-2_fggdfg --username 117979111 --user-attributes Name="email_verified",Value="true"
```

You can do all this perfectly with the aws SDK 2